# SQL: error on invalid column name that does exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, bids

i'm trying to create a package that will copy data from a file and put it into a new table. so far so good.
but should the package fail for some reason, i want it to truncate the newly added data.
so,  i want it to execute this statement

> IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id =
>   OBJECT_ID(N'TABLE_NAME') AND type in (N'U')) DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME
>   WHERE date='2015-11-10'

but i keep getting this error:
"Error: 0xC002F210 at Delete From MYTABLE, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_..." failed with the following error: "Invalid column name 'date'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly."

but MYTABLE does have a column called "date"... i just can't figure out what the problem is, and google hasn't been able to help me.

Comment: `Date` is a keyword. Put it in brackets like this: `[date]`. Might want to do the same thing with `[type]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "date" is a reserved word, try using [date]

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'TABLE_NAME') AND [type] in (N'U')) DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE [date]='2015-11-10'
```

SQL Server reserved Words: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Chuck the column name in brackets as date is a reserved word in SQL Server

[Date]